# How to retrieve RouterState from the @ngxs/router-plugin inside and before other states initialise

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, ngxs

In a previous application using Angular 8.0.0 and 3.5.0 NGXS I was able to retrieve the RouterState via a SelectSnapshoot from the @ngxs/router-plugin in other states before the components rendered. However, in my new application the RouterState returns undefined as if it has not been initialised before the other states start running. I can't even get the SelectSnapshot on my component now. This was a core feature of my app and pretty important for page refresh, so I was hoping if someone could tell me how it is possible to achieve with NGXS.

I've tried to use the new RouterDataResolved parameters inside the state but this does not work either.

I have created a simple StackBlitz just showing how I believed I used to be able to retreive the router state.   Am I missing a setting somewhere or what's going on? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nm7cj7

Comment: why wouldn't you just create an issue on their github?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just select the RouterState as any other state using select?

```
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor(private store: Store) {
      this.store.select(RouterState).subscribe((value) => {
        console.log(value);
      });
  }
}
```

I think you might be better off using the existing @ngxs/router actions instead of creating your own GetRouterState stuff.

Check out [router.actions.ts](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/packages/router-plugin/src/router.actions.ts) on the NGXS repo.